# django sql join with like

Tags: django

I have following models

```
class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    views = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "artist"
        ordering = ['-views']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Song(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey("Artist")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    lyrics = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    views = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "song"
        ordering = ['-views']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

and would like to get all the rows that match the keyword. 
I can do it in sql and returns what I want. here is the sql;

```
SELECT song.name, song.path FROM song JOIN artist on song.artist_id = artist.id WHERE artist.name LIKE %keyword% || song.name LIKE %keyword% || song.lyrics LIKE %keyword%
```

but could not figure out how to do that in django. should I use custom sql? do you guys have better idea?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matching_songs = Song.objects.filter(Q(name__contains=keyword) | Q(lyrics__contains=keyword) | Q(artist__name__contains=keyword))
```

See [Django docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) on Q objects for more details

Answer (score 1):

After 2 hours of digging and asking myself why I am not getting expected results, I realised that `__contains` is case-sensitive while `__icontains` is not.

So, for example if we have person named "torres" in database and supply "Torres" to `__contains` then it will return nothing while `__icontains` will return "Torres".